# Parsing a blank string to DateTime makes App Unclosable

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

When I use a blank string as a parameter in `DateTime.Parse`, after closing all windows, the application is still running, like this:

```
txtBirthDate.SelectedDate = ("" == empBirthDate) ? DateTime.Parse("") : DateTime.Parse(empBirthDate);
```

But when I enter a date, like for example `11/26/1995`, the app stops running after I closed all the windows:

```
txtBirthDate.SelectedDate = ("" == empBirthDate) ? DateTime.Parse("11/26/1995") : DateTime.Parse(empBirthDate);
```

Is this a feature of the `DateTime.Parse`, or is it something else?

Comment: First of all, `DateTime.Parse("") ` throws a `FormatException`, why are you throwing an exception intentionally like this?

Comment: I think a little bit of context to this would help a lot. Also not trusting input is a good idea just by default. I would investigate using `DateTime.TryParse` to check the input - might help.

Comment: @mok I didn't know, but there is indeed an error popping after I put the code into a try-catch,maybe that's the reason why the app doesn't stopped running after closing all windows. If having a blank string is impossible, what alternative can I do when the `empBirthDate` does not have a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime.Parse` is not capable of parsing empty string, instead for that you can return `DateTime.MinValue` or else `DateTime.Today` if the input string is null or Empty. in this case the code will be like this:

```
txtBirthDate.SelectedDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(empBirthDate) ? 
                                   DateTime.MinValue : 
                                   DateTime.Parse(empBirthDate);
```

If you are aware about the format of date in the variable `empBirthDate` then it became more easier with `TryParseExact`, in this case the value of the `inDate` variable will be `DateTime.MinValue` if the conversion failed, or else it will have the correct value. So you can try like this:

```
DateTime inDate;
string currentFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime.TryParseExact(empBirthDate, currentFormat , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out inDate);
txtBirthDate.SelectedDate = inDate;
```

Comment: This is nice. Just curious,  is `String.IsNullOrEmpty(empBirthDate)` better than `"" == empBirthDate`?

Comment: Yep it's better than `==`  comparison

Answer (score 0):

Basically un-lucky is right. But the first code example will still throw exceptions in case of invalid input. While the second example has to be modified in the following way:

```
DateTime inDate;
string currentFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(empBirthDate, currentFormat , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out inDate))
{
  txtBirthDate.SelectedDate = inDate;
}
```

Also instead of using DateTime.MinValue consider using nullable DateTime (defined as 'DateTime?'). In some situations this would be more appropriate.